# Wrong product stock when importing magmi with pending orders

Tags: magento, magmi

I'm syncronizing an ERP software with Magento via Magmi.

Consider the following: all available units of a product are in a pending order, so the product is not available in the store. If a Magmi product import is done while the order is pending, the product’s stock returns to the original quantity and it goes back to the store.
This means the stock won’t be correct until there’s another import from the ERP software after the order is fulfilled.

Am I missing something? If not, how easy is it to set the correct product availability upon the import?

I imagine it's "only" a matter of subtracting the product quantities present in pending order to the quantities being imported. Of course, the worst case scenario is probably the product already being out of stock in the ERP software and thus ending up with negative stock.... and more importantly, with a dissatisfied customer.

I probably could minimize the risk of ending up with negative stock by synchronizing more often, but I'm still dependant on how quickly the website orders are fulfilled.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make sure that there is 1 true resource for your (stock) data. Because stock updates are coming from ERP to Magento, we can argue that ERP is the leading resource. In that case you can consider use a real-time update towards the ERP when an order is set to pending (use an observer on sales_order_save_after).

This way, you'll have the following situation:

1. Product stock is imported to magento.
2. Order is placed and is pending.
3. Real-time update is done and ERP receives updated stock (decrement).
4. Now you have 2 situations:

   1. Order is cancelled and ERP receives updated stock (increment).
   2. Order succeeded, no update towards ERP required.

This way, the ERP is always aware of how Magento perceives your stock and there will not be any issues when you receive a 'full' stock update towards Magento.

Comment: That sounds good, (although I would like to avoid changing the ERP DB). Can you explain the use of the observer? Would it be like a trigger?

Comment: @Mike: There isn't really another way, unless you crank up stock updates and disable Magento's stock decrementing behavior, but that will leave you with gaps.

Comment: @Mike: An event is dispatched when orders (actually most entities) are saved. You can use them to do something real-time rather than based on an interval. There are plenty of resources describing events/observers in magento :)

Comment: I understand I can have a php file in app\code\local\SampleObserver\Sales\Model\Order\Save\After performing a function. In this case, how can I obtain the data in the order? I obviously need the order's product SKU and quantity...

Comment: The observer method is passed a transport object containing the order. You can get the order by doing something like $observer->getOrder(). From there, you have a sales/order object and can do anything you'd ordinarily do with such an object. 

You may want to consider creating a separate question for this though :)

Comment: @Mike: And to make a shameless plug for one of my own modules - consider if ApiImport (https://github.com/danslo/ApiImport) is not a valid alternative to Magmi in your case.

Comment: I think the stock update is not an option. I need to find a way to add a new order to the ERP system. consider this: an order via magmi decrements stock, but later when someone fulfills the website's order, it will decrement the stock again...